# Parent loose focus on child Iframe focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I have a `div` element that has an `iframe` inside it. On my parent, I have some *styles* that work based on the `div` focus state. When I click on the `iframe` inside the `div`, my `div` loses focus. I Tried some workarounds but none seemed to work as per my requirement.

Also, I can not use `pointer-events: none` because I need the iframe to be interactive. Here is a demonstration of my problem:

**My Component:**

```js
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div tabIndex={0} className="container">
      <div className="some-child">Inside the parent</div>
      <iframe
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        src="https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1"
        title="Google"
        loading={"eager"}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Styles.css:**

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:focus .some-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you need the iFrame to be interactive, you are going to have to find a workaround to your div losing focus. Think if you are typing - where do those keystrokes go?